rails cancancan upgrade 3.0.2 -> 3.5.0 issue
ruby 2.7.8
rails 6.1.7.7
cancancan 3.5.0
I have upgraded cancancan in favor of upgrading rails version to 6.1.7.7, but now ability file is behaving really weird specially the ones with STI. I have to rearrange the permission sequence to pass my test cases.
Is anyone know what have changed or it is only related to my application.
There is an open issue as well in cancancan for STI
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/809
for example
can :manage, [User::Base,
        User::Customer,
        User::Employee]
can :read, UserFollowedRecord, post_id: Post.accessible_by(self).ids


with the above while looking for Post.accessible_by(self).ids adding type in query with 'customer' and 'employee' and breaks with type column not defined on post
but the below snippet works correctly
can :manage, [User::Base]
can :read, UserFollowedRecord, post_id: Post.accessible_by(self).ids
can :manage, [User::Customer,
        User::Employee]


"weird behavior" is not very descriptive but This Change was merged into 3.2.1 and This Change is part of 3.5.0. Maybe one of those is your issue?

@engineersmnky i have updated my question to make things more clearer.

I think you have already answered your own question with the Github issue; however This linked one provides some additional context as well as some hacky "solutions".

there are 2 things mentioned 1. is disabling rule_compressor and it is not working for me and the other one is monkey patching Sti_detector class which one you are suggesting @engineersmnky

I am not suggesting either. All I am suggesting is that you have already determined that there is an issue, specifically related to STI and the order of the abilities and have identified that the same or similar issue has been brought to the attention of the team that supports cancancan. I am not sure beyond that I (or we) can solve this for you since the issue is with the library and not your code.

@engineersmnky for now i have decided to go with 3.1.0 version and monkeypatch the https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_5_adapter.rb#L41 method to get rid of initial issue undefined method resolve_column_aliases. I have to upgrade to 6.1 and this is the best solution in my mind.
PLease let me know if you have any other solution thank you.

The long term solution I would look into is transitioning to Pundit. While there is a little more too wrap your head around initially it's a more flexible and more importantly SOLID design. CanCan was designed in the awkward time in history when everything was made as a DSL and doesn't deal well with complexity.
